# Javascript TypeError: var is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Working with Vanilla NodeJS. (i.e. no framework)

Have a function in `index.js` called `toData()` that I want to use inside an event handler.

the `toData()` function is exported as the default export in `index.js`.
The relevant portions of `index.js` looks like this:

```
function pushToData(input, title) {
  data[title] = input;
  console.log(data);
  if (isDataFull()) {
    mainEvents.emit("format-export");
  }
}

module.exports = pushToData;
```

The file where I'm importing and attempting to use it looks like this:

```
const mssql = require("mssql");
const events = new require("events");
const tagList = require("./tag");
const toData = require("./index");

const tagEvents = new events.EventEmitter();

const sqlAuth = {
   /*....SQL Auth Details....*/
};
tagEvents.on("b2bloaded", function(data) {
  data = tagList(data, "ESB", "CustomerID");
  toData(data, "B2B");
});
/*....Additional event handlers omitted due to similarity...*/

function generateSqlData(item) {
  const pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(sqlAuth, err => {
    switch (item) {
      case "B2B":
        pool
          .request()
          .query(
            `select top (100) * from [AspDotNetStoreFrontB2B].[dbo].[Customer]`
          )
          .then(res => {
            tagEvents.emit("b2bLoaded", res.recordset);
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
        break;
      /*....Other Cases Omitted as they operate similar....*/
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  generateSqlData
};
```

The big issue is that I get a:

> ```
> null: TypeError: toData is not a function message: "toData is not a function" stack: "TypeError: toData is not a function
> at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (c:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\Migratron\sql-actions.js:36:3)
> at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:160:13)
> at pool.request.query.then.res (c:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\Migratron\sql-actions.js:87:23)
> at <anonymous>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)"
> ```
>
> **proto**: Error {constructor: , name: "TypeError", message: "", …}

I'm not sure why it's not running as expected. Why is the function not defined properly, or not running when called?

Comment: Did you debug to see what is in toData ? What is your index.js?

Comment: What does your `index` file look like? How are you exporting your function?

Comment: Could you post the related index.js please.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to export your fonction like this :

```
export.pushToData(input, title) {
  data[title] = input;
  console.log(data);
  if (isDataFull()) {
    mainEvents.emit("format-export");
  }
}
```

and use it this way :

```
const mssql = require("mssql");
const events = new require("events");
const tagList = require("./tag");
const toData = require("./index");

const tagEvents = new events.EventEmitter();

const sqlAuth = {
   /*....SQL Auth Details....*/
};
tagEvents.on("b2bloaded", function(data) {
  data = tagList(data, "ESB", "CustomerID");
  toData.pushToData(data, "B2B");
});
```

Comment: That kind of looks like the same thing with extra steps. How is it different from what I've already done? I'm not criticizing, just not sure what this approach adds to the equation.

Comment: The way you call toData is not calling a function, it's calling an import. You can try to call it taht way `toData.pushToData()`

Comment: And there are no extra steps, just a different way to export your function in your index.js file.

Comment: okay, still had trouble so I just `require()`'d it inline and it worked.